# Faster way to filter a list of objects in to another list based on a condition

Tags: c#, performance, linq, xamarin.ios

I have a list ( ios contacts ) which i need to filter based on the firstname , last name and email starting with the match string. I have about 5000 contacts and currently it takes about 2 seconds to filter results. Here is my code.

```
    var personList = people.FindAll (p => 
                        (p.LastName != null && p.LastName.IndexOf (findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) || (p.FirstName != null && p.FirstName.IndexOf (findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                            || (p.GetEmails ().ToList ().Count > 0 && (p.GetEmails ().ToList ().FindAll (e => e.Value.IndexOf (findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).Count > 0)))

                    );
```

Can anyone suggest a faster way to do this? Thanks

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: Does MonoTouch support `PLINQ`? Newer iOS devices are multi-core AFAIK and should benefit from that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IndexOf(..) == 0` to compare is the same  as asking if that string (Name, LastName or Email) starts with the given `findstr`. If instead you want to know if the string contains de `findstr` use the `String.Contains` or `IndexOf(..) != -1`

I would also separate those predicates for code clarity like this:

`Func<string, bool> filter = s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && s.StartsWith(findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

`var personList = people.Where(p => filter(p.FistName) 
                                 || filter(p.LastName) 
                                 || p.GetEmails().Select(e => e.Value).Any(filter));`

Now if you want you can do that in parallel:

`var personList = people.AsParallel().
                         Where(p => filter(p.FistName) 
                                 || filter(p.LastName) 
                                 || p.GetEmails().Select(e => e.Value).Any(filter));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FindAll`, and calls to `ToList` and then `Count` , use:

```
var personList = people.Where(p => (p.LastName != null 
    &&  p.LastName.IndexOf(findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    || (
        p.FirstName != null && p.FirstName.IndexOf(findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
        || (p.GetEmails().Count > 0 && (p.GetEmails()
                                            .Where(e => 
                                                e.Value.IndexOf(findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).Count > 0))
             ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `Any()` instead of `ToList().Count > 0`
- `First()` and then check if it matches the condition instead of `IndexOf (findstr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0`

You can find full list of queues [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).